# currency format in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I use these following codes. When i use these codes it shows $ symbol with the value. I just wanna show value in the correct format without any symbol.

```
private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
        new CultureInfo("en-US");
    int money = 12346789;
    TextBox1.Text = money.ToString("C");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the format `"C"` is the correct way to format currency that will be culture-specific / culture-aware.

It sounds like you're actually trying to use a custom format. You could [write a formatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter.aspx) for that, or you can just do this:

```
TextBox1.Text = money.ToString("#,##0.00");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TextBox1.Text = String.Format("{0:N2}", money);
```

Comment: can i use masktextbox instead of textbox?